# Get exact location in google map via longitude and latitude in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, gps

Is it possible to get the exact location or address in vb.net using longitude and latitude in google map? I am currently working on a project and using a gps tracker to track a location, it is sending me the longitude and latitude of the location then with use of web browser I can find it in the google map. I need to get the exact location (ex. 1 Center Ct, Cleveland, OH 44115, United States) and put it in my windows form.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfYi1.png

Comment: have you checked this? https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net

Comment: Google Maps Geocoding API using reverse geocoding. Simple REST interface. Free for low volume. Refine definition of "exact location" if you need more.